# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable - unable to display my training dataset scatter plot

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a dataset with 200 columns and 650 rows and i want to draw a scatter plot but it is showing "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

I read the excel sheet with the sheet name as Training I tried putting all the column names

```
# The snippet below will load the Thurstone Interest Schedule dataset and create a scatter plot matrix of the dataset.
# Scatter Plot Matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
df = pd.read_excel (r'F:\Thurstone Project\Training Dataset.xlsx', sheet_name='Training')
names = ['Physicist', 'Mechanical Engineer', 'Inventor', 'Chemist', 'Electrical Engineer',.........]
data = pd(df, names=names)
scatter_matrix(data)
plt.show();
```

I got following error when i run the above code

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c204cb64f383> in <module>
      6 df = pd.read_excel (r'F:\Thurstone Project\Training Dataset.xlsx', sheet_name='Training')
      7 names = ['Physicist', 'Mechanical Engineer', 'Inventor', 'Chemist', ...... ]
----> 8 data = pd(df, names=names)
      9 scatter_matrix(data)
     10 plt.show();

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I expect the output to be Scatterplots...

Answer (score 0):

The error is spot on. You imported the pandas library as pd and then in your code, you have `pd(df, names=names)`, which is an invalid usage. It looks to me like you're trying to create a dataframe and supplying the names to the columns with `pd(df, names=names)`. The correct call should be `pd.DataFrame(data, columns=names)`

However, this is unnecessary actually, as you already get a dataframe out of `df = pd.read_excel (r'F:\Thurstone Project\Training Dataset.xlsx', sheet_name='Training')`. Thereafter, you can apply the names to your columns by calling the following line:

`df.columns = ['Physicist', 'Mechanical Engineer', 'Inventor', 'Chemist', 'Electrical Engineer',.........]`